# Routing MSMQ messages from one queue to another

Tags: msmq, biztalk

Is there some standard configuration setting, service, or tool that accepts messages from one queue and moves them on to another one? Automatically handling the dead message problem, and providing some of retry capability? I was thinking this is what "MSMQ Message Routing" does but can't seem to find documentation on it (except for on Windows Mobile 6, and I don't know if that's relevant).

Context:

I understand that when using MSMQ you should always write to a local queue so that failure is unlikely, and then X should move that message to a remote queue. Is my understanding wrong? Is this where messaging infrastructure like Biztalk comes in? Is it unnecessary to write to a local queue first to absolutely ensure success? Am I supposed to build X myself?

Comment: Turns out about 80% of my confusion was because the main place to go if you want to learn about MSMQ is *not* MSDN, which is where I was looking, but rather on TechNet: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753070(v=WS.10).aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Hugh points out, you need only one MSMQ Queue to Send messages in one direction from a source to a destination. Source and destination can be on the same server, same network or across the internet, however, both source and destination must have the MSMQ service running.

If you need to do 'message' routing (e.g. a switch which processes messages from several source or destination queues, or routing a message to one or more subscribers based on the type of message etc) you would need more than just MSMQ queue.
Although you certainly can use BizTalk to do message routing, this would be expensive / overkill if you didn't need to use other features of BizTalk. Would recommend you look at open source, or building something custom yourself.

But by "Routing" you might be referring to the queue redirection capability when using HTTP as the transport e.g. over the internet (e.g. [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa919490.aspx) and [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731558%28WS.10%29.aspx.)).

*Re : Failed delivery and retry*

I think you have most of the concepts - generally the message DELIVERY retry functionality should be implicit in MSMQ. If MSMQ cannot deliver the message before the defined expiry, then it will be returned on the Dead Letter Queue, and the source can then process messages from the DLQ and then 'compensate' for them (e.g. reverse the actions of the 'send', indicate failure to the user, etc).

However 'processing' type Retries in the destination will need to be performed by the destination application / listener (e.g. if the destination system is down, deadlocks, etc)

*Common ways to do this include:*

- Using 2 Phase commit - under a distributed unit of work, pull the message off MSMQ and process it (e.g. insert data into a database, change the status of some records etc), and if any failure is encountered, then leave the message back onto the queue and the DB changes will be rolled back.
- Application level retries - i.e. on the destination system, in the event of 'retryable' type errors (timeout due to load, deadlocks etc) then to sleep for a few seconds and then retry the same transaction.

However, in most cases, indefinite processing retries are not desirable and you would ultimately need to admit defeat and implement a mechanism to log the message and the error and remove it from the queue.

But I wouldn't 'retry' business failures (e.g. Business Rules, Validation etc) and the behaviour should be defined in your requirements of how to handle these (e.g. account is overdrawn, message is not in a correct format or not valid, etc), e.g. by returning a "NACK" type message back to the source.

HTH

Comment: Thanks nonnb! Reading through your recommendations, I ended up both finding lighter weight alternatives to BizTalk like NServiceBus and Mass Transit, but more importantly figuring out which layers *were not necessary* and now we can simply deliver msmq messages over a VPN link to the remote system rather than have all of the intermediary layers.

Comment: Out of interest, you may also want to look at AMQP based Queues like RabbitMQ and [Azure Service Bus](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-bus-amqp-overview/). In Rabbit, exchanges can route messages to another exchange with just configuration, no extra code needed.

Answer (score 4):

MSMQ sends messages from one queue to another queue.

Let's say you have a queue on a remote machine. You want to send a message to that queue.

So you create a sender. A sender is an application that can use the MSMQ transport to send a message. This can be a .Net queue client (System.Messaging), a WCF service consumer (either over netMsmqBinding or msmqIntegrationBinding, BizTalk using the MSMQ adapter, etc etc.

When you send the message, what actually happens is:

1. The MSMQ queue manager on the sender machine writes the message to a temporary local queue.
2. The MSMQ queue manager on the sender machine connects to the MSMQ manager on the receiving machine and transmits the message.
3. The MSMQ queue manager on the receivers machine puts the message onto the destination queue.

In certain situations MSMQ will encounter messages which for some reason or another cannot be received on the destination queue. In these situations, if you have indicated that a message will use the dead-letter queue then MSMQ will make sure that the message is forwarded to the dead-letter queue.

Comment: This was useful to me. Some more info for anyone trying to make sense of this question is that after some testing I discovered that Computer Management | Services and Applications | Message Queuing | Outgoing Queues is the right place to look for where the messages live until they are delivered.

Comment: @tom Whilst a reasonable description of MSMQ, it does not answer the OP's question of _"Routing MSMQ messages from one queue to another"_.  Point-to-point transfer is not routing.

Comment: Agreed - @khanfx please unmark my post as answer and award to another answer.